# What is the most straight forward way to install manjaro as a lightweight cli only distro?

Tags: linux, command-line, manjaro, linux-distributions

I'm looking to install manjaro on a thin client with limited resources.
I'd like to install without any desktop environment as I'll basically only use this via the terminal and via ssh however it doesn't seem clear what the recommended way to do this is.

It seems like manjaro architect *used* to be a good option but [is apparently no longer maintained](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/maintainer-s-wanted/19502)
I've seen some guides on how to [customize a build the "arch way"](https://amaikinono.github.io/install-minimal-manjaro.html), and something similar [using manjaro tools](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-create-your-own-manjaro-spin-with-manjaro-tools/1355) and even [create custom isos](https://www.maketecheasier.com/6-tools-to-easily-create-your-own-custom-linux-distro/) but it's not clear to me which way is the most straight forward.

To be clear I'm looking to create a build that contains the following:

- A manjaro based image with the basic unix tools (grep, sed, ect)
- Developer tools such as gcc, git, docker, vim, emacs ect
- lack of non-essential software (i.e. no need for a gui, libreoffice, file explorer, ect)

Comment: But then why Manjaro? Sounds like you actually want Arch.

Comment: I would go for arch however I do like that manjaro is contains packages which are less bleeding edge (with the option to install arch packages if needed) and I'm more familiar with some of the manjaro specific tooling (like mhwd-kernel).